# To Win The Right To ****************

Tags: no-computers, chess

I found this nice little problem on Tim Krabbe's website the other day. I found it so unique and beautiful, that I felt compelled to share it here as a puzzle to be solved. Please do not use a computer and do please don't look up the answer! Try to use your own brain power!

It's White to move and reach a winning postion in 7 moves.

**Gady Costeff (Israel), 3rd Place, World Chess Composition Tournament, 2003**

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly new to chess puzzles - is the idea here to make moves as white and assume black will make the best possible move? I've done puzzles where you can force a set of moves by keeping the opponent in check but that doesn't seem possible here.

Comment: I assume it is more than one move

Comment: It looks like White can't put Black in check here, let alone checkmate. So yes, it has to be more than one move. However, if White is to win, then all of White's moves must force Black's moves by threatening checkmate.

Comment: I should note that I've looked at both the given solution and Stockfish's analysis and they actually disagree. rot13(va cnegvphyne, fgbpxsvfu pnerf yrff nobhg gur juvgr cnja naq ba zbir fvk jvyy gnxr gur ovfubc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s the answer:

> 1. Qa4 Rxf3 2. Qa6+ Qxa6 3. bxa6+ Ka8 4. Ba3 Rxb1+ 5. Bc1 Rb8 6. Bb2 Rbf8 7. 0-0-0 ..
>
>
>  From the title To Win The Right To **************** I think the asterisks refer to queenside castling which means the title was actually **To Win The Right To Castle**, which gave white safety from being threatened to be mated and the advantage in the following moves.

Comment: Have you considered base64(MS5RYTQgbG9va2luZyB0byBmb3JjZSBhIHRyYWRlIHdpdGggMi5RYTY=)?

Comment: ah, I copied the wrong 4 set move my bad. @RewanDemontay see update

Comment: @RewanDemontay Was the asterisks refer to the right to castle? After your clarification, it was an enjoyable puzzle.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Done, feel free to correct me :) Hope you had another enjoyable puzzle soon

Answer (score 4):

I initially thought the answer was something like

> 1.Qa4, Rxf3||Rh5 (Rook has to move or it will be lost after Queen trade)
> 2.Qa6+, Qxa6
> 3.xa6+, K?? (Not sure if capturing the pawn or moving to a8 or c6 is better)
> 4.Ba3, (Start developing pieces, immediate threat is handled)

Given the poster's comment confirming the first four moves:

> 1. Qa4 Rxf3 2. Qa6+ Qxa6 3. bxa6+ Ka8 4. Ba3 Rxb1+

I believe the continuation is as follows, for the following reasons.

> 5. Bc1 Rb8 Black must prevent H8^Q
> 6. Bb2 Rh3 Still trying to prevent promotion
> 7. H8^Q bRxh8  White forces a trade
> 8. Bxh8 Rxh8
> 9. O-O-O if possible, anyway, white seems pretty far ahead at this point.